# Onfling and OnTouch does not work together

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview, touch-event, onfling

I have an Expandable Listview. I am implementing a deletion of the listItem on Swipe Left of each item.

I am using custom adapter for populating listview items.

```
public class InsightsListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
@Override
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    row = inflater_.inflate(R.layout.insight_list_item, null);

    final GestureDetector gdt = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());
    row.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            swipedViewPosition_=groupPosition;
            swipedView_=v;
            gdt.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });

    return row;
}
```

I am using GestureListener like below

```
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 200;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

private class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) {
            System.out.println("Left swiped--------");
            removeListItem();
            return false; // Right to left
        }  
        return false;
    }

}
```

As it is a Expandable Listview i implemented some click functionalities in the acticity

```
        insightList_.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, long id) {
                System.out.println("Group clicked---------");
                showClear(true);
                selectedItem_ = null;

                return false;
            }
        });
```

But now on OnFling is getting called. but not OnGroupClick()

When i return false from onTouch event function from adapter, OnGroupClick is getting called but not OnFling().

Either Fling will work or OnGroupClick but not both simultaneously.

Comment: set ontouchlistner on listview and chek it work or not..

Answer (score 1):

On ontouch event of the row

> row.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {[..]

you return true, so no more touch event will be called after that, change to return false and the touch event will be downfall to the next child view.